# Automatically Rewrite html,php,css or any file extension using htaccess?

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, file-extension

is there a way to automatically remove the file extension from the url?

for ex:

the user types

```
www.website.com/page.html
```

it will automatically convert the page to:

```
www.website.com/page
```

and if possible with a `/`:

```
www.website.com/page/
```

it must be automatic that the `.htaccess` will force the url to rewrite the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You try to do this wrong way. You do not want to remove extensions. You want to **rewrite** extensionless requests to real files. So if user type

```
http://foo.bar/file
```

your server would serve as it was requested

```
http://foo.bar/file.html
```

To do this you need `mod_rewrite` (or equivalent) and set rewriting rules according to your needs. The same module is also used to make URLs looking nicer, so instead of

```
http://foo.bar/script.php?id=34&smth=abc
```

you can have

```
http://foo.bar/script/id/34/smth/abc
```

or even

```
http://foo.bar/script/34/abc
```

[Read more on mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: the otherway around is it possible if the user types with a html it will remove it?

Comment: Yes, you can rewrite in any fashion. If you really need to do as described for any purpose then there is no problem. but if you want to achieve "nice URLs" then doing my way will cause less problems

Answer (score 0):

I use this in .htaccess (index.php is handling the pages):

```
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php?page=home
// Result: http://domain.com/home/
```

If you want it more dynamic:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1
// Result: http://domain.com/any-page/
```

For more data you might need when requesting a page:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
// Result: http://domain.com/data-page/15/
```

If you want to just get the called page without the index part:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

To remove extensions the user adds:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things. First you need to change all of your links to the URLs without extensions, then you need to create a 301 redirect to redirect browsers and bots that still may have the old URLs with extensions to the new nice looking ones. This a server response of a new location, it's not a rewrite (which is an on-the-server-only internal URI rewrite).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(.*)\.(html?|php)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
```

This makes it so when someone types `http://www.website.com/page.html` in their browser, they get redirected to `http://www.website.com/page/` and the new URL will appear in the browser's URL address bar.

Now the second thing you need to do is internally change it *back* to the valid resource, since `/page/` doesn't exist, it'll return a 404.

```
# need these so we don't clobber legit requests, just pass them through
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# now check the extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.htm -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.htm [L]
```

You'll just need to put these in the htaccess file in your document root.